# Raspberry Pi2 roscpp failed during Indigo installation

Tags: ros, raspbian, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I cannot install ROS Indigo on the Raspberry Pi 2 model B with Raspbian **Jessie**(no problem with **Wheezy**).
At each time, it fails when it compiles roscpp with the command :

`sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo`

I followed the official instructions that are [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi).

I even tried to compile myself *libconsole-bridge-dev* and *liblz4-dev*.

I cannot join the .txt because i'm a new user. So, here is the error :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6pyfz9ubi5fty6/error_roscpp.txt?dl=0

Have you any idea or solution?

Thanks !

**EDIT** :

There is also a strange thing that happen : the raspberry pi 2 gets his ram AND swap satured !
And once the Raspberry completely crashed.
Before it prints the error, the raspberry is *lagging* so even if you have another ssh terminal opened, you can't do anything in it. Even the refresh of *top* doesn't work !

Here is the error :

```
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/single_subscriber_publisher.cpp.o
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/build.make:146: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/publisher_link.cpp.o'     failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/publisher_link.cpp.o] Error 4
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:308: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'roscpp':
Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roscpp && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219575/raspberry-pi2-roscpp-failed-during-indigo-installation/) by [amof](https://answers.ros.org/users/24711/amof/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-10-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-21**:
Please run `catkin_make -j1` and copy & paste the error text (and some surrounding lines) into your question. Linking to dropbox is not very nice, as that will make this question (and any possible answers) worthless if / when you delete that file. Use the *edit* button/link to update your question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-21**:
Please reformat your copy/paste using the *Preformatted text* button on the toolbar. It's the one with `101010` on it. That would make this much more readable. Be sure to re-copy/paste the error, as the quotes you used now have changed the lines (inserted formatting characters).

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-10-21**:
Looks like it's asking you to report a GCC bug! Never seen this one. That's very interesting... I bet you can get them to fix it quickly, or at least tell you what happened.

**Comment by [amof](https://answers.ros.org/users/24711/amof/) on 2015-10-21**:
@gvdhoorn : Done ! Thanks for the advices.
@allenh1 : Must I report the GCC bug ??!

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2015-10-21**:
It's possible it's your swap space. I've has problems like this on my Pi's (Although not the early on in the build). Make sure you have about 1Gb of swap avaliable and it active

Mark

**Comment by [amof](https://answers.ros.org/users/24711/amof/) on 2015-10-21**:
I just tested it.
I put 1Go of swap and it worked ... Strange because the Rpi 2 has 1gb of ram !
It took apparently 1500 mb of ram-swap to compile roscpp ...
What can necessite all that memory ?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2015-10-21**:
To be honest I have no idea. Have put that as the answer though :)

**Comment by [amof](https://answers.ros.org/users/24711/amof/) on 2015-10-21**:
It could be interesting to investigate on it !

**Comment by [shahidare](https://answers.ros.org/users/25190/shahidare/) on 2015-11-28**:
I am also suffering from same problem. Did you found any working solution?

**Comment by [amof](https://answers.ros.org/users/24711/amof/) on 2015-11-28**:
Yes, you can increase your swap space in /etc/dphys-swapfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible it's your swap space. I've has problems like this on my Pi's (Although not the early on in the build). Make sure you have about 1Gb of swap avaliable and it active

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2015-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hobbert Evergreen](https://answers.ros.org/users/28992/hobbert-evergreen/) on 2017-01-09**:
Two days going mad until find this answer!! Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on 2022-02-10**:
Thx a lot! [Here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-swap-file/) is a how-to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are willing to install Ubuntu 14.04 on your Raspberry Pi 2, you can install ROS binaries by following: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM . (this skips the entire compilation process).

Note that this only works on the Pi 2, because it has a more recent processor and supports Ubuntu. This won't work on the original Pi.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1